# Случайная выборка из базы данных с нумерацией по порядку строк

Tags: sql

Есть таблица пользователей в таблице есть поля `id int(11) AI, login varchar(255), email varchar (255)`.

Нужно выбрать 10 случайных пользователей, чтоб первой колонкой в выборке был N - номер по порядку в выборке.

```
SET @cnt:=0; SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+1 AS N, login, email FROM users as u1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @cnt:=0; SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+1 AS N,login,email FROM (SELECT login, email FROM users as u1 ORDER BY RAND() ) u2 ORDER BY N LIMIT 10
```